# How to fix typeError 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, typeerror

I want to count my facebook page likes with python but I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    print "Page Name:"+ page_data['name']
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

There are several related posts about this but I can't figure it out

Here is my used code.

```
import urllib2
import json
import time

def get_page_data(page_id,access_token):
    api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/"
    fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+page_id+"?fields=id,name,likes,unread_notif_count,link&access_token="+access_token
    try:
        api_request = urllib2.Request(fb_graph_url)
        api_response = urllib2.urlopen(api_request)

        try:
            return json.loads(api_response.read())
        except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
            return "JSON error"

    except IOError, e:
        if hasattr(e, 'code'):
            return e.code
        elif hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            return e.reason

while 1:
    page_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx" # username or id
    token = "XXXXXXXX"
    page_data = get_page_data(page_id,token)

    print "Page Name:"+ page_data['name']
    print "Likes:"+ str(page_data['likes'])
    print "Unread notifications:"+ str(page_data['unread_notif_count'])


    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: `page_data` is an int, the code for the error which you returned from the function

Comment: Ok ok. You have a solution?

Comment: You need to go back and rethink  your code if page_dara is not what you're expecting.

Comment: can you print page_data and tell us what its value is?

Comment: Sure. its printing constant 400 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple return points in your `get_data` code, returning different data types,  but the way you're using it,  implied you always expect it to be a dict. At Stone point it returns an interview,  when it expects something else.

Either change your `get_data` method so it always returns a dict,  or preferably, change it so it only returns in one place and one data type (your dict)  and let it throw an exception when it fails.

Comment: Airght gonna try it. I am noob so it will take a while. Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: @edriskeyam let me know how it goes